# Woocommerce Storefront theme customise product pages and category pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product, storefront

I'm trying to create specific templates for both the category pages and individual product pages. It would be good to lay out various attributes on the pages according to where I would like them. However, beyond the endless 'hooks' that storefront uses... I can't find the places to modify actual code.

Does anyone know how to do this? I don't want to be modifying CSS specifically - I want to create new templates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create new templates, you should override multiple files from `plugins/woocommerce/templates` to `themes/strefront_or_child/woocommerce`, this is the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) article, check `loop/` and `global/` folders too.
Hope this helps a little.